# apache ant not installing properly

Tags: java, ant

I did download the apache-ant-1.8.4 and unzip the folder then placed into c drive after that I checked the apache-ant installed or not with command "**ant -version**" then command prompt gave me error like

> 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

I already set environment variable of Java and ant. please see my environment variable shown below..

> ANT_HOME  -> C:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin  
> JAVA_HOME ->
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin

I am using windows xp. please tell me where I am doing wrong. I trying lot but not achieve my goal. please somebody help me to solve this bug.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the dir to C:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin and use ant command. If it runs then your environment variable is not set properly.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to say. please explain

Comment: on the command prompt type `cd C:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin` press enter key. After that type `ant` and see the output,

Comment: I got msg;- Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Comment: Follow the below post by seelenvirtuose. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :
- set your environment variable on System properties
a: variable : ANDROID_HOME
       value    : your Path\phonegap\sdk
b: variable : ANT_HOME
       value    : your Ant HOme\java\apache-ant-1.9.2

I hope this help for your problem solve

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not *installed*, it is unzipped into any folder you wish.

If you open a command prompt and try to run any executable, it is your operating system (Windows in this case) that searches for it. Where does it search? In the current directory (Windows does that, Linux fortunately not), and in all directories that are part of the PATH environment variable.

What I always do (and I always recommend):

1) Add an environment variable ANT_HOME pointing to the directory, where you placed Ant. For example `ANT_HOME = C:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.4`. Have a look: this variable does *not* point to the `bin` directory.

2) Add the following to your PATH variable:

```
PATH = ...;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

This is the same way, I also do with Java, Maven, JBoss, and whatever tool I use. If you ever change your installation (maybe also to a new directory), you must only change the appropriate *home* variable. The path will be adjusted automagically.

---

EDIT (I just saw your `JAVA_HOME` variable)

Change your `JAVA_HOME` variable to contain `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37`. Then add this also to the `PATH` variable:

```
PATH = ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```